# A seeming Catch-22 re: developing ARM solutions on a non-ARM device

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, arm, winrt-xaml

In order to see my XAML forms in the designer, I have to set the Debug platform to x86 (if I set it to ARM, I get a msg in the designer that the XAML form cannot be shown when set to ARM). So: how would I know if I'm doing something (such as using some feature or programming construct) that actually will not work on an ARM device? IOW, I want to have my cake (visualize the XAML forms) and eat it, too (have it work on ARM, even though I'm telling Visual Studio to treat this is a x86 project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mayank said, set your project to target Any CPU. This will allow it to run on any device, Intel, or ARM. Do not be concerned about doing something that you are not allowed to do. If you stay within the SDK you are guaranteed to be safe. If you start trying to hack the system, then you run the risk of targeting something for an Intel chip, but if you do this you will not be certified for the store :)

Answer (score 1):

That's why you should select `Any CPU` instead.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any CPU should work if you are not using native code. If you are - well, then you do need to use x86 to use the designer, but don't worry - Blend lays things out differently than a running app anyway, so if you want pixel perfect layout - you need to run the app, take screenshots and calculate your pixel pushing offsets with a magnifier anyway.